# Chewed, Wielded and Legendary - What am I?

Tags: riddle

*I have teeth, but can be chewed.*

*I alone am worshipped, but those who wield me are too.*

*I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.*

What am I?

**Edit:** Huge apologies as I was using yield and not wield. I think that may have been what was throwing some people off.

Hint:

> The one you would bite is not physically the same as the one you would wield.

Hint 2:

> The concept of wielding is important - don't disregard it as other answers have.

Hint 3:

> In the past I was worshiped symbolically not physically - but not in modern day

Comment: You should hold off the hints. There are people from some countries who haven't yet seem the riddle.

Comment: Gotcha - I'll edit them out and save them for a bit later

Comment: Though note that they are still in your edit history and can be viewed...

Comment: Well if people really wanted to see them still they can go into that, I don't know how to remove them from that. I'll add the hints back in later if it's not answered.. People haven't been quite on track so far

Comment: Really sorry to people who appropriately thought of yield with their scenario, while some thought of wield - I edited the question to reflect the change. :/

Comment: -1 because there are too many potential answers to this riddle. Furthermore, changing "yield" to "wield" doesn't invalidate any of the existing answers.

Comment: @March_Ho It does invalidate some, you don't wield gold, or a bison (at least literally) for example. And if I add the hints it narrows down a little bit and makes it a little more precise. Do you think I should add hints back in now?

Comment: Is *legend* used as metaphor?

Comment: @Techidiot No, by resides among legends, meaning this thing is often seen alongside legends

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Second try since the 'yield' line was changed to 'wield':

You are searching for a...

> Trident

I have teeth, but can be chewed.

> The three spikes are the teeth, Trident chewing gum

I alone am worshipped, but those who wield me are too.

> Its a precious weapon. And the god Poseidon is whorshipped.

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.

> Well a god might be a legend, but the item sure isn't

My first try, OLD ANSWER: 
I go with:

> GOLD

I have teeth,

> Gold grillz

but can be chewed.

> Gold is a kinda easy to bend metal. So some people bite it, to see, if it's real [Athletes chewing gold medal](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8810/is-biting-a-gold-coin-a-working-method-to-verify-its-authenticity)

I alone am worshipped, but those who yield me are too.

> Gold digger

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.

> Funerary goods. Like in a Pharaoh's grave.

Comment: That's a really clever answer, but not what I intended.

Comment: For the chewed line, we can think about athletes biting medals too! :P

Comment: Unfortunately not it though @Green... The chewed line is related to a twist on the object's name

Comment: @n_palum I added another answer

Comment: You might like to add a separate answer: your second guess fits much better.

Comment: @pb8330 Does it make a difference? I would just leave it as it is.

Comment: People might like to up-vote one and not the other (but it's fine either way).

Comment: Also Trident is the name of the UK's Nuclear program https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_nuclear_programme

Comment: Trident is what I was looking for! The gum was my twist! I was going with the idea that Taoism has the Trident as a symbol for the highest authority in their Heaven, thus worshiped, but yours works too :)

Comment: Also if anyone was curious the Latin origin of the word translates to three teeth which is where that comes from.

Comment: I agree with @pb8330. Best leave it as it is for now, but in future you should definitely add a new answer rather than editing an existing one.

Answer (score 13):

Are you:

> a Key?

I have teeth,

> Keys used to open doors have teeth

but can be chewed.

> These same Keys are 'bit' to create their unique shape

I alone am worshipped, but those who yield me are too.

> The 'Key' as in the ultimate answer, and those who provide them, are often worshipped

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.

> 'Legend' as in the kind on a map, also called a 'Key'

Comment: Hmm I really like this one too, but alas not what I am going for. Interesting take on chewed, but not correct.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

> A crown

```
I have teeth, but can be chewed.
```

> A tooth with a chip may be given a crown, but like Tobi said about gold, it can be chewed.

```
I alone am worshipped, but those who yield me are too.
```

> In countries, like England, with a royal family. The family/lineage is called the crown and it is sometimes thought of as its own entity. Also, people that wear crowns may be worshipped.

```
I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.
```

> Crowns often appear in legends, but real rulers can also wear them.

Comment: Another clever response, seems to be a trend thinking about gold stuff. But not what I am going for still.

Answer (score 3):

My partial answer so far:

> gum

I have teeth

> anatomically, teeth are in your gums.

but can be chewed.

> chewing gum

I alone am worshipped, but those who yield me are too.

> ???

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.

> google says there is legend gum (legendgum.com)

Comment: Another interesting approach, you're half in the right direction is all I will say. But not right

Comment: Kind of like the Night at the Museum movie. *You dum dum, me want gum gum.*

Answer (score 1):

So I'm coming up with

> Truth

```
I have teeth, but can be chewed.
```

> This is somewhat of a stretch, but the truth has teeth in the sense that it has power, and many people have "chewed over" (pondered) it.

```
I alone am worshipped, but those who yield me are too.
```

> Almost all religions are in some way a search for truth, and people who discover truths are usually praised.

```
I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.
```

> Most legends have a kernel of truth to them, but by definition the truth is not a myth.

Comment: Hmmm.. Interesting thoughts but no not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> The american Bison

I have teeth, but can be chewed.

> Bison have teeth, also are eaten.

I alone am worshiped, but those who yield me are too

> Native Americans worshiped the bison, those who yield one (warriors) are celebrated, perhaps worshiped

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not

> Bison are legends of the wild american past but are not mythical beasts

Comment: Nope not it, but I another good thought process.

Answer (score 1):

I am:

> A good law

I have teeth:

> A good law can be enforced and has teeth.

I am worshiped:

> A good law is revered which a form of worship.
> Those who yield to a law are also revered because they support their society.

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not:

> Some laws are remembered to apply to things which they do not or have legendary abilities.   There are good laws therefore good laws are not mythical.

Comment: No not really, kinda stretching some of those

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A pencil

I have teeth, but can be chewed

> Having teeth as in tooth marks upon it? People chew on pencils when nervous.

I alone am worshipped, but those who wield me are too

> Pencils (or writing tools) are worshipped in some cultures, writers are worshipped too.

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not

> In the context that legendary writers must have used pencils once, but the object itself is not mythical.

Comment: Interesting but not what I am going for.

Comment: I'd say that in any case, you can't rely on pencils having teeth as having tooth marks, if you're already saying they've been chewed.

Comment: Yeah, was a long shot that one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> A sports trophy (used by boxers and other fighters)

I have teeth, but can be chewed.

> Trophies get plated or chipped with the winner's name.

I alone am worshipped, but those who yeild me are too

> Trophies are sought after, and are given to the victor yielded by the previous champion

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not

> Athletes are legends to some degree, and their prizes are real.

Comment: Nope. You can't chew that or any variation of it really.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

> power.

I have teeth

> as in, can cause consequences.

Can be chewed

> power food, or some kind of brand name. (Seems there's a chewing gum as well as some sort of power gum fishing line?)
>
>  Power itself is what many people seek above all else and powerful people are held in awe.
>
>  Legends often deal with people or items of great power, but power itself is real.

Answer (score 0):

Are you...

> A dog

I have teeth, but can be chewed.

> A dog has teeth, and can be eaten.

I alone am worshipped, but those who wield me are too.

> Dogs are worshipped in some religions. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_worship#Dog): "...The dogs are worshipped as a part of a five-day Tihar festival..."
>  Also, 'wield' can be defined as: have and be able to use (power or influence), so dogs can be wielded

I reside among legends, but a myth I am not.

> Many famous figures have dogs, one noteworthy person being the queen of England. Here is a [Quora article](https://www.quora.com/Who-are-famous-people-who-had-have-relationships-with-dogs) about other famous people who have dogs.

Comment: Interesting, but the answer was already revealed :)